# IN Accurev I need to create CLI Commands For checking if file is dll an status is overlap

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

need to create CLI Commands For
1) checking if file is dll an status is overlap

2)Command on how to take latest of estream

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on the AccuRev forum also.

1. accurev stat -s  -o -ffl | grep -e .dll
2. I am guessing you want to get the latest version from a stream. If this is the case, 'accurev pop -v  -R -L  .'

Example:
accurev pop -v Test -R -L /tmp .